# Processing insists pause() is not a function, when it very much is

Tags: audio, processing

Aite, [first poster here, pls don't bash]
So, I'm using the sound library, which I of course remembered to import, and works just fine, proof being given by the fact that all the other functions I used work as expected and give no problems neither in editor nor in execution.
Except, of course, for this little bugger of a pause() function, which I wrote as per below using no different a syntax from all the other functions, only to find out Processing isn't very keen on accepting its existence.
Problem shows both using 3.3.6 and 3.5.

Oh, and also, apparently isPlaying() returns an int, what's up with that?

If, as I'd suspect, that single line below won't be enough code to couple with the info to get to the bottom of it, here's a Dropbox link to the code (since it uses a bunch of files) so you can test it yourself.
It kinda won't work if you try to run it as is tho because it messes up when trying to load all the songs (in the last line of setup), yeah I kinda need some help with that too... works fine if you only load the first one tho!

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/di7mwit0w2l4513/AABipGDAdoKx277f8Hg_ZfhDa?dl=0

(Please, don't expect clear, extensively commented coding. I started working on this way before I learnt that was a thing. Deeply sorry. Of course, you can ask away about anything baffling you)

What did I try, er, writing it well???
I used .play(), .stop(), the volume ones, and they all, as per stated, work fine.

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile[] songs= new SoundFile[1];
void setup(){
    songs[0]=new SoundFile(this,"Small Bump.mp3");
    songs[0].play();
}
void draw(){
}
void keyPressed(){
if (songs[0].isPlaying()==1)songs[0].pause();
}
```

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] directly in your post?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Done!

Comment: You code uses an `i` variable that's never initialized.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh sugar coated liquor, I'm sorry about that!
I twas initialized in the original sketch, but I trimmed that bit off as it wasn't the one causing problems. Fixed now, sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sound library I had installed was 1.3.2, or something of the likes.
All the references I'd read were for 2.0+.
Having updated that through the "add library" menu, all was solved.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy your code into my Processing editor, I get a couple errors:

```
songs[0]="Small Bump.mp3";
```

The `sounds` array holds instances of `SoundFile`, but you're trying to store a `String` value here. Maybe you're looking for the `SoundFile` constructor?

```
if (songs[0].isPlaying()==1)
```

The `isPlaying()` function returns a `boolean` value, but you're comparing it to an `int` value.

```
songs[i].pause();
```

You haven't declared this `i` variable anywhere. Probably meant for this to be a `0`.

If I fix all of these errors, then your code compiles fine.

You might want to take a look at the reference for the Sound library [here](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/index.html).

Comment: The top and bottom errors are me messing up the trimming of bits of code I'm not concerned with like the utter buffoon I am. I indeed meant for that to be a 0. Fixed that and scheduled some self punishment later in the day.
The middle one is, as I'd actually mentioned, another headache of mine: the function actually returns an int for me, and I have no idea why!

Comment: Found the culprit! Apparently, these functions were changed/added in an update I hadn't installed, contrary to what some early checking had lead me to believe. Sorry for having wasted your time and thanks for proving me my code itself wasn't the source of the problem, making me take a second look  at what else it could've been.